# Is there an efficient way to create colormesh from scatter data of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe like this;

```py
X   Y  VALUE
140 45 124
15 129 219
189 90 125
```

I'm trying to create a 2D color mesh from this dataframe by summing all the `value` within each "grid." Right now I'm doing it by

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

step = 5
xx = np.arange(0, 200+step, step)
yy = np.arange(0, 200+step, step)
array = np.empty(xx.size * yy.size)
ctr = 0
for y in np.nditer(yy):
    for x in np.nditer(xx):
        grid = df[(df['X'] >= x) & (df['X'] < x + step) \
                & (df['Y'] >= y) & (df['Y'] < y + step)]
        value_sum = grid['VALUE'].sum() if not grid.empty else 0
        array[ctr] = value_sum
        ctr += 1
mesh = array.reshape((yy.size, xx.size))
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, mesh)
```

This does serve my purpose, but it is very slow since I'm using Python for-loop. Is there a way to use numpy broadcast feature to avoid using python for-loop and create the same mesh (ndarray)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do the upper limit exclusive with `df['X'] <= x + step`? This might make some entries in `VALUE` being added more than once in the mesh output.

Comment: It works better for my particular purpose--but that's a good point!

Comment: *fixed inequality signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [np.histogram2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html#numpy.histogram2d), using the values as weights:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

xs = [random.randrange(0,201,1) for _ in range(100)]
ys = [random.randrange(0,201,1) for _ in range(100)]
value = [random.randrange(0,500,1) for _ in range(100)]

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(xs, ys, bins=42, range=None, normed=None, weights=value, density=None)
plt.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, hist)
```

This runs around 10x faster than a loop version on my machine.

Comment: `histogram2d` worked and was much faster, thanks! Is there a way to take the mean of values in each grid instead of summing them?

Comment: @dedededaio try using np.histogram2d again, but without the weights, and then using this to divide the first result element-wise with np.divide

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like this?

```
mesh = np.zeros((len(xx), len(yy)))
for row in df.itertuples():
    mesh[row.Y//step, row.X//step] = row.VALUE
plt.pcolormesh(yy, xx, mesh)
```